# ExceptionMapper methods not getting invoked in Jersey Project

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I've a custom exception mapper which uses the @Provider annotation,

```
@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException>{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException arg0) {

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(arg0.getMessage(), 404);
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                        .entity(errorMessage)
                        .build();

    }

}
```

The problem is despite this I continue to get the Tomcat Server Error page. This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>io.soumasish.SimpleRestApi.Resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now I've checked this question on SO

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413239/toresponse-in-jersey-exceptionmapper-does-not-get-invoked)

This suggests two solutions,

```
using classes.add(EntityExceptionMapper.class); worked for me thanks a lot @Provider does not seems to work



 Adding the following line to the init
    jerseyServletFactory.addExceptionMapper(new MyCustomExceptionHandler());
```

Can someone help me understand where can I do either of the two steps. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what version of jersey do you use? you need to configure web.xml so that jersey will know to scan the package of your provider class.

Comment: @MaxG edited the question to include the complete web.xml

Comment: What package is the  mapper in? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33399641/2587435)